# To disable all text box with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, textbox

I'm newbie, i still learn to make something with Jquery, i hope you can help me, please don't judge me, help me thankyou:).

`<input type="text" name="text1" id="txt" disabled>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="txt2" disabled>
<input type="text" name="text3" id="txt3" disabled>
<input type="button" value="Enable" name="button1" id="btn">`

and i have script jquery like this:

`$(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                count = count%3;
                $('input[type="text"').attr('disabled',true).eq(count++).attr('disabled',false);
            })
        });`

i can't make on fourth click all disable and on fifth click all enable, can u help me? thankyou:)

Comment: on 6th click what is expected?

Comment: `$('input[type="text"')` is missing `]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, It will enable every input on fifth click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                if(count > 3)
                    $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled',false);
                else
                  $('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled',true).eq(count++).attr('disabled',false);
            })
        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/70/)

Comment: and you copied the typo

Comment: @epascarello sorry fixed that.

Comment: @Mritunjay then, on checkbox how to make all uncheck on fourth click and all check on fifth click?

Comment: @SandySatyo same you have to use `type="checkbox" & .attr('checked',true)`.

Comment: like this "$(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('#btn3').click(function(){
                if(count > 3)
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
                else
                  $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('disabled',false).eq(count++).attr('checked',true);
            })
        });"

Comment: @SandySatyo I don't know that, you must be missing something.

Comment: ya i'm forgot to replace id button. but why when fifth click it doesn't work? sorry if i many asked

Comment: @SandySatyo see the fiddle & match according to that, I think fiddle is working

Comment: @Mritunjay I've continuously try but on fifth times is not work

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
$('input[type=text]:enabled:first').attr('disabled',true);
```

run this every time you click that `button`.

[**`:enabled`jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)
[**`:first` jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)